# Use cookie-free domains with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, static, dns

After trying to find the answer, I still cannot figure it out.

I have my domain www.bragdeal.com
I created a subdomain static.bragdeal.com and pointed it to the folder 'static' in the root

I placed all of my images in bragdeal.com/static/ folder
When I ran gtmetrix, it tells me to `Use cookie-free domains`

On my website, I point to the images like this:

```
<img src="static/test.jpg">
```

In my htaccess I have:

```
# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# 1 WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Is my only solution buying a completely new domain to store all my static content on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point to your images using the sub-domain you created.
`<img src="http://static.bragdeal.com/test.jpg">`
Another alternative would be to put them on Amazon S3 -- which also reduces some traffic to your server.

Comment: You mean <img src="static.bragdeal.com/test.jpg"> ?

Comment: Yes... point being that you need to reference them in your HTML img tags to the static.bragdeal.com domain....`http://static.bragdeal.com/path-to-image...` (you need to put the protocol in there -- http://)